# inserting data into mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to insert data into MongoDB using java but I get an error when I try to compile the code. I have no idea what's causing the error. I want to add a new book entry.

```html
error message:
 required: String,Object
  found: List<Document>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
UseMongoDB.java:61: error: method put in class Document cannot be applied to given types;
book.put(publishers);
```

```html
private MongoCollection<Document> books = db.getCollection("books");

 void insertanewbook() {
  
  
  Document book = new Document();
  book.put("title", "test");
        book.put("category","test");
                book.put("price",12.3);

                List<Document> authors = new ArrayList<Document>();
  Document author = new Document();
                author.put("first_name","jonn");
                author.put("last_name","james");
                author.put("country","t");
                author.put("website","www.test.com");
  authors.add(author);
  book.put(authors);

  List<Document> publishers = new ArrayList<Document>();
  Document publisher = new Document();
                publisher.put("publish_date",new Date());
                publisher.put("name","test");
                publisher.put("country","test");
  publisher.put("website","www.test.com");
  publishers.add(publisher);
  book.put(publishers);
                
  books.insertOne(book);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you posted...

```
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

In other words, method [put](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) requires two arguments and you are supplying only one. From the code you posted, you are missing the *key* in the call to method `put()`. Just add the relevant key, for example

```
book.put("publishers", publishers);
```